Python Can-bus comunication doesnt stop sending messages
Good day.
I have the following python code:
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import can
import os
import csv
import pdb

os.system('sudo ifconfig can0 down')
os.system('sudo ip link set can0 type can bitrate 125000')
os.system('sudo ifconfig can0 up')

def main():
    with can.Bus(interface='socketcan', channel = 'can0',receive_own_messages=True) as bus:
       
####### Envia un mensaje y a la vez guarda lo enviado en un archivo csv 

        print_listener = can.CSVWriter("in.csv")
        can.Notifier(bus, [print_listener])
        bus.send(can.Message(arbitration_id=0x14,data=[1], is_extended_id=False))

#########################################################################################

        #message = bus.recv()
        #print(message.arbitration_id)

        time.sleep(1.0)
        print_listener.stop()

        bus.shutdown()
       
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    #os.system('sudo ifconfig can0 down')

Connected to USB, I have a USB/CAN converter (https://www.amazon.com/Pibiger-PU2CANFD-C-Converter-SavvyCAN-Busmaster/dp/B0BX9H6W8R).
The code sends a CAN message, and saves that message in to a csv file (in.csv).
The part of writing the code in to a csv file works fine. The problem I have is that when seeing the output of the usb/CAN converter in to an oscilloscope, it doesnt stops sending the message, it keeps repeating it. I thought it could be because it was waiting for a confirmation, but CAN does not wait for a confirmation.
This is the library I am using: https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html
Thanks a lot in advance,
Best regards.

Do you have another node connected to the can bus? Someone needs to ACK the messages otherwise sending was not successful and the controller will try again.

Thank you @mspiller. No, there was nothing connected to the output.
Yes, I have put an esp32 at the other side (just now), and it worked (The message is received correctly). There is one thing I do not understand tho, Isnt CAN supose to not need a confirmation, so it should just send the message??.. As for my understanding, ACK if 1 when the message is being send, and then 0 when is a reply (Or that is what I understood from some documents I have read).
Thanks a lot in advance.
